# Recommend a textbook in algebraic geometry

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

Please recommend a textbook in algebraic geometry for a beginner.
I will be doing algebraic geometry for the first time.

Comment: What do you mean by "a beginner"? What kind of background do you have?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880542/prerequisites-for-algebraic-geometry/

Comment: Before uploading question, You should search that similar to that you want to find.